# Using Math.pow in Java to determine surface area of a cube AND also a difficulty with 'skipping'

Tags: java, math, pow

I'm writing a simple program to determine some math values and I'm stuck on a problem where it asks a user for a length of a side of a side of a cube, then to output the surface area (using Math.pow and the formula 6a^2). I get the formula and everything but maybe I'm entering this in wrong? I keep getting a different answer than what I'm supposed to...

```
System.out.print ("Please enter the length of a side of your cube: ");
a = in.nextDouble();
System.out.printf ("Surface area of your cube is : %.3f\n", Math.pow (6*( a,2 )));
```

Does this problem deal with spacing or what? It just keeps giving me expected error for the parenthesis but I'm sure everything looks okay... 
I also tried to shift things about such as (( a,2 )*6) and I would get the same wrong answer and expected error ):

~

Another thing I am running into is when I ask the user for two numbers separated by a space, to look for the larger one with Math.max, it works, but then it uses the same numbers to ask for the smaller number. I DO NOT want the user to use these same numbers as I want them to enter some other new numbers...

```
System.out.print ("Please enter two numbers separated by spaces: ");
a = in.nextDouble();
System.out.printf("Larger of the first two numbers is %.3f\n", Math.max ( a,a ) );

System.out.print ("Please enter two numbers separated by spaces: ");
a = in.nextDouble();
System.out.printf ("Smaller of the first two number is %.3f\n", Math.min ( a,a ) );
```

I am new to programming. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one post. Create a separate question for the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incorrect, `Math.pow(base, exponent)` expects 2 parameters :-

```
System.out.printf ("Surface area of your cube is : %.3f\n", Math.pow (6*( a,2 )));
```

Should be :-

```
System.out.printf ("Surface area of your cube is : %.3f\n", 6 * Math.pow (a,2) );
```

And, for finding the square, you should stick to trivial concept, i.e., doing `(a*a)`, rather than opting for Math.pow(base,exponent)

[Note -> Multiplication would cost easier than calling the pow() method].

> when I ask the user for two numbers separated by a space, to look for
>   the larger one with Math.max, it works, but then it uses the same
>   numbers to ask for the smaller number. I DO NOT want the user to use
>   these same numbers as I want them to enter some other new numbers...

Firstly, that should be a separate question. But, even then for achieving the same, you need the knowledge of loop so that you could run a task for pre-defined number of times.

As this problem is simple, you could simply ask for more doubles below, after calculating the max(). But, that'd be somewhat complex. I suggest you to tep ahead in a step by step approach. Follow the books/tutorials and keep in that order.

Comment: No one should use Math.pow to calculate a square; better to say a*a in this case.

Comment: @duffymo - Was adding that, but, you commented first.

Comment: I'm just trying to get used to using Math... this worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Xela - You're encouraged to keep learning and do keep visiting SO for other programming-related queries too. Cheers, :)

Answer (score 2):

```
6a^2
```

This means six times the square of `a`.

```
Math.pow (6*( a,2 )
```

This means nothing. It's not even valid syntax. You need:

```
6*Math.pow (a,2 )
```

or more simply

```
6*a*a
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second question you ask, I suggest you to put the numbers that user input into a `HashSet`, and then use `contains` method to check if the numbers user input has been used previously. You can check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) for reference of the `HashSet`.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I'd appreciate that if you put up any simpler and easy-implemented solutions.

Comment: I agree. This is how I would implement the second requirement. @Am_I_Helpful I don't find anything 'complex' or 'unclear' (or '"unclear"', whatever that means) about this answer.

Comment: @EJP - Given that OP states in question *"I am new to programming."*, I don't see how it'd be easier for OP to apply data-structure concepts! Please read the question once again.